# SelectManyMenu - can't select item when after InputTextArea

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I place an `InputTextArea` and a `SelectManyMenu` (in that order) in a page, I can't select any items in the menu - nothing is highlighted when I click on them.
However, if I change the order on the page (`SelectManyMenu` *before* the `InputTextArea`), then everything works as it's supposed to.

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head/>
<body>
<h:form>

    <p:selectManyMenu id="testSMM">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3"/>
    </p:selectManyMenu>
    <br/>
    <p:inputTextarea id="testITA"/>

</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head/>
<body>
<h:form>

    <p:inputTextarea id="testITA"/>
    <br/>
    <p:selectManyMenu id="testSMM">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3"/>
    </p:selectManyMenu>

</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

All I did was put one tag before the other. What am I missing here?

ps: This doesn't happen with an `InputText`.

**EDIT:**

The browser console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined
    at components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0:1`, and even though the generated html has the same content (but not in the same order, obviously), the `InputTextArea` has different attributes when I check the 'elements' tab in the console:

working code:

```
<textarea id="j_idt4:testITA" name="j_idt4:testITA" cols="20" rows="3"
maxlength="2147483647" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtextarea ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-inputtextarea-resizable"
role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="true"
data-autosize-on="true" style="overflow: hidden; overflow-wrap: break-word; height: 63px;"
</textarea>
```

buggy code:

```
<textarea id="j_idt4:testITA" name="j_idt4:testITA" cols="20" rows="3"
maxlength="2147483647" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtextarea ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-inputtextarea-resizable"
</textarea>
```

Comment: Well, start by making your code a real full one. You nowhere have a value attribute. And did you check the browser developer console?

Comment: I trimmed everything down to the simplest piece of code that would still reproduce the behavior I experienced. My original code had value attributes, but they didn't change anything. I did check the browser console but couldn't make much sense of it, as I'm a beginner.

Comment: Ok good to know leaving  the value attributes out does not make a diiference. What does the console tell you? And please state your PF version.

Comment: I checked the source code (the generated html), and they're exactly the same - the only difference being the order of the elements. I'm using PF 6.0.
Is there something specific I should look into through the console?

Comment: The console logging... check for errors.... And did you compare via view-source or 'inspect element'?

Comment: I'll edit my question with more info.

Comment: So you tried PrimeFaces 6.1 or 6.2, just to see if it solves this issue?

Comment: Just did it right now. Primefaces 6.1 solved the issue. My first thought was I was doing something wrong or missing something in my code. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Great... Maybe using PF 6.2 is even better (and 6.3 is comming soon I think). Please remember these things for debugging. Always check the browser deverloper console (especially if 'order' is relevant, then most likely there is a javascript error on a former component that prevents the next ones to be initalized). And always (in an [mcve] check the latest version. And e.g. check if another component instead of the one not working also has a problem (like you did now but for the inputTextArea with an inputText)

Comment: Typo: I used 6.2, not 6.1. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been some small issues in this regard in PrimeFaces 6.0 related to components not loading the right core javascript. These are fixed in a 6.0.x elite release and 6.1 community release.